# Удаление всех файлов с ftp php curl

Tags: ftp, curl, php

Накатал код для удаления всех файлов с фтп. Но он работает в 4 раза медленнее FileZilla. Что не так? Какие есть недочеты в логике?

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(1);
ob_end_flush();
$mtbegin = microtime(1);

$useragents = str_replace("\r\n", '', file('useragents.txt'));

//формат
//ftp://login1:password@ftp.host.ru
//ftp://login2:password@ftp.host.ru
//ftp://login3:password@ftp.host.ru

$count = file('loginsftp.txt');
for($i=0;$i<count($count);$i++){

$useragent = $useragents[mt_rand(0, count($useragents)-1)];

$logins = str_replace("\r\n", '', file('loginsftp.txt'));
$url = array_shift($logins);
file_put_contents('loginsftp.txt', implode("\r\n", $logins));

$result = CURL_FTP($url, 0, 0);
$content = $result['content'];
$arr = explode("\r\n", $content);
$ftp = '';
foreach($arr as $v) $v !== '' ? $ftp[] = $v : '';
if($ftp == ''){
    echo $i+1 .' '.$url.' <b style="color:green;">пусто!</b><br />';
    continue;
} else {
    $files = ''; $dirs = '';
    foreach($ftp as $v) preg_match("#\.#", $v) ? $files[] = 'DELE '.$v : $dirs[] = $v;
    if($files !== '') $result = CURL_FTP($url, $files, 0, 1);
    if($result['errno'] == 21) $files = ''; $dirs = ''; foreach($ftp as $v) !is_dir($url.'/'.$v) ? $files[] = 'DELE '.$v : $dirs[] = $v;
    if($dirs !== ''){
        for($a=0;$a<count($dirs);$a++){
            $urldir = $url.'/'.$dirs[$a].'/';
            $result = remove_ftp($urldir);
            if($result == true) continue;
        }
    }
  }

$result = CURL_FTP($url, 0, 0);
if(strlen($result['content']) == 0){
    echo $i+1 .' '.$url.' <b style="color:maroon;">файлы удалены!</b><br />';
} else {
    echo $i+1 .' '.$url.' <b style="color:red;">kuinya какая-то! (<i>не все файлы удалились. возможно проблема с CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT или правами на файлы</i>)</b><br />';
}

continue;

}

if((round((round(microtime(1)-$mtbegin, 2))/60)) > 1){
echo '<br />Всего времени затрачено: '; echo '~'.round((round(microtime(1)-$mtbegin, 2))/60) .' мин<br /><br />';
} else {
echo '<br />Всего времени затрачено: '; echo '~'.round(microtime(1)-$mtbegin, 2) .' сек<br /><br />';
}

function remove_ftp($url){
    $result = CURL_FTP($url, 0, 0);
    $content = $result['content'];
    $arr = explode("\r\n", $content);
    $ftp = '';
    foreach($arr as $v) $v !== '' ? $ftp[] = $v : '';
    $dir = preg_replace("#ftp://.+/#U", "", $url);
    $urldir = preg_replace("#/[^@:/]+/$#U", "/", $url);
    if($ftp == ''){
        $dir = array("RMD $dir");
        CURL_FTP($urldir, $dir, 0, 1);
        return true;
    }

    $files = ''; $dirs = '';
    foreach($ftp as $v) preg_match("#\.#", $v) ? $files[] = 'DELE '.$dir.$v : $dirs[] = $v;
    if($files !== '') $result = CURL_FTP($urldir, $files, 0, 1);
    if($result['errno'] == 21) $files = ''; $dirs = ''; foreach($ftp as $v) !is_dir($url.'/'.$v) ? $files[] = 'DELE '.$v : $dirs[] = $v;
    if($dirs !== ''){
        for($b=0;$b<count($dirs);$b++){
            $urldir = $url.$dirs[$b].'/';
            $result = remove_ftp($urldir);
            if($result == true) continue;
        }
    }
    remove_ftp($url);
}

function CURL_FTP($url, $deletearray, $upload=0, $delete=0){
    global $useragent, $infile, $filetoupload;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, 1); // если нет бинарных файлов (картинки, фавиконы и тп), вроде как работает быстрее
    if($upload == 1){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $infile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filetoupload));
    }

    $delete == 1 ? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_QUOTE, $deletearray) : '';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    $content['content'] = curl_exec($ch);

    $content['errno'] = curl_errno($ch);
    //if(curl_errno($ch) !== 21){
    //    echo 'Curl errornumber: ' . curl_errno($ch) . '<br />';
    //    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    //}
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Уффф... что-то тут слишком много понаписано для такой просто задачи.

Работает медленно потому, что вы делаете 1 реквест на удаление одного файла.

1 запрос - получаем список файлов, 2-й - RM и через пробел указываем все файлы... в кавычках.

Comment: сенкс за ответ! только я не понял /*2й - RM*/ как с помощью этого удалить не пустые папки?
под файлами я имел в виду все, что есть на фтп(папки, странички, картинки и тп).
мне тоже сначала казалось, что все просто, пока я не узнал, что RMD не удаляет не пустые каталоги.

Comment: Ну, тогда еще добавится реквестов - количество папок * 2 (один на список файлов, второй на удаление).

Comment: сорри, не догоняю. т.е. первый реквест (запрос?) - строится дерево всех файлов(и папок) на фтп, второй - все это удаляется? а как это реализуется...
array('
RMD /papka1/papka2/papka3',
'RMD /papka1/papka2/',
'RMD /papka1/');
т.е. надо получить что-то типа такого и загнать его на удаление. причем удаляться все должно последовательно... тогда возникает вопрос - как построить этот массив "на удаление"?:) все равно же рекурсивно все каталоги надо будет обходить? тогда за счет чего получим сокращение времени?

Comment: Вы правы, всё равно придется рекурсивно обходить все каталоги. А также увеличивается время на каждый "реквест-коннект" к фтп ... иначе курл и не работает.

Если делать всё в ранком одной сессии (коннекта) то всё должно быть намного быстрее

Answer (score 0):

А почему не [FTP на уровне PHP](http://php.su/articles/?cat=protocols&page=015)?

Comment: Я попробовал через эти функции сначала. Но что-то у меня зависало все при использовании <a href="http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php">ftp-nlist</a>. Попробовал курл, срабатывал моментально, решил на нем сделать. Сделал. Только в 4 раза медленнее работает FillZilla, что лишает смысла весь мой быдлокод. А <a href="http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rmdir.php">ftp-rmdir</a> удаляет непустые каталоги?

Comment: Нет.

Comment: Смысл тогда от этих функций, если все равно придется рекурсивно удалять?..

Comment: не пришлось бы писать так много кода , который к тому же и тормозит